# Alignment Slider and TextBlock together inside ListView column

Tags: wpf, listview, slider

I have `ListView`  and i inserted  `Slider` and `TextBlock` in the same `column`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate2">
    <Grid Margin="-7" >
        <Slider Name="sliderColumn"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle}" Width="80"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=sliderColumn, StringFormat={}{0}}" FontSize="11" Foreground="White"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Bu when the `Slider` value changed it become unreadable:

[image]

Any suggestions how to fix it and make sure to display only integer numbers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your slider Like this by ading these two properties in slider `TickFrequency` and `IsSnapToTickEnabled`

```
<Slider Name="sliderColumn"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="80" TickFrequency="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"/>
```

Comment: Thanks that workd but is it possible to take a little the label to the right ? currently if the slider value is higher then 10 - the label hide the right side of the slider (i try Padding="20,0,0,0" but this still not enough)

Comment: @markyer you want slider value more than 10? and please mark as accepted if its fixed your issue

Comment: My slider lave has maximum value of 100 but when this value has more then 2 digits the label hide the right side of the slider

Comment: @markyer its due to the margin of the grid try to alter that you will get full value

Comment: I removed all the margin and it still hapenning